# Can you change the MapSource in Mapview to just an image?

Tags: python, kivy, mapview

My map should only be a .png image that repeats across the globe. I am using the Mapview flower from kivy.garden, it seems that only a url can be used as the mapsource, tho just a plain image.png would be better as a source for me.

Comment: Could you specify more details ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.